# Remove linkbuttons when exporting to excel

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have this class for exporting repeater to excel.

***rpt.RenderControl(hw);***   at this line i get the repeater code so i want to remove the linkbuttons from there how to access it and remove linkbuttons,
the changes should be in this class
Also can we do this with if else condition  ?

Thank You in Advance and Happy New Year!!!!

```
public void Export(Repeater rpt, string FileName)
      {
        
          HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
          HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;
          HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename="+ FileName +".xls");
          HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = "";
          HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
          StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
          HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);


          
          HttpContext.Current.Response.Output.Write("<table>");
          sw.Write("<tr>");
          sw.Write("<h3>Company Name<h3>");//Enter Company Name Here
          sw.Write("</tr>");
          sw.Write("<tr>");
          sw.Write("<h3>Address<h3>");//Enter Company Address 
          sw.Write("</tr>");
          sw.Write("<tr>");
          sw.Write("<h3>Contact<h3>");//Enter Company Contact Details 
          sw.Write("</tr>");
          sw.Write("<tr>");
          sw.Write("<h3>Email<h3>");//Enter Companys Emails 
          sw.Write("</tr>");
          #region trying foreach
          List<Repeater> rpts = new List<Repeater>();
         
          //foreach (Control control in rpts)   //remove linkbuttons 
          //{
          //    switch (control.GetType().Name)
          //    {
          //        case "HyperLink":
          //            rpts.Add(new Literal { Text = (control as HyperLink).Text });
          //            break;
          //        case "TextBox":
          //            cell.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = (control as TextBox).Text });
          //            break;
          //        case "LinkButton":
          //           // rpts.Add(new Literal { Text = (control as LinkButton).Text });
          //            rpts.Add(new Literal { Text = (control as LinkButton).Text });
          //            break;
          //        case "CheckBox":
          //            cell.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = (control as CheckBox).Text });
          //            break;
          //        case "RadioButton":
          //            cell.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = (control as RadioButton).Text });
          //            break;

          //    }
          //    cell.Controls.Remove(control);
          //}
          //foreach (Control hlk in rpts)
          //{
          //    if (hlk is LinkButton)
          //    {
                 
          //        LinkButton pp = (LinkButton)hlk;
              
          //        pp.Enabled = false;
          //        pp.Visible = false;
          //    }
          //}
          #endregion
          rpt.RenderControl(hw);   
          
          HttpContext.Current.Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
          HttpContext.Current.Response.Output.Write("</table>");
          HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
          HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
      }
```